# Alternative way to express StateT Functor instance definition

Tags: haskell, functor, state-monad

I'm implemented the `Functor` instance for `StateT` in the following manner

```
import Data.Tuple (swap)

newtype StateT s m a =
    StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }

instance Functor m => Functor (StateT s m) where
    fmap f (StateT g) = StateT $ \s -> fmap (fmapSwapTwice f) (g s)
        where fmapSwapTwice f tup = swap $ f <$> swap tup
```

But I'm not *wholly* satisfied with my solution, because it requires me to import `swap` from `Data.Tuple` and `fmap` it over the tuple twice in order to apply `f` to the first element.

To me this seems like a common enough pattern that would have its own abstraction or perhaps there is an alternative way to express the `Functor` instance that I can't think of which doesn't require `swap` at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the `Bifunctor` instance of tuples. Use [`Data.Bifunctor.first`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:first) instead of `fmapSwapTwice`.